# Getting error while executing the mysql query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(packages.id) AS rowCount,
       packages.packageCode
FROM packages
INNER JOIN prices ON packages.packageCode = prices.packageCode
WHERE TRUE packageCode LIKE '%EPOP%'
ORDER BY packageName ASC
```

There is an error with where clause, can anyone please helpme out..

Comment: what is `TRUE packageCode` if its a column name then enclose in backticks.

Comment: @Abhik Chakraborty No luck, still getting same error, yes packageCode is a column name

Comment: I am asking about @Naveen what is TRUE? It is boolean value of column name?

Comment: @Sadikhasan i have no idea what is that TRUE means, if i remove TRUE m getting ambiguity error, seems it is a keyword of mysql

Comment: What error might that be? Maybe use " group by packages.id " before the order by statement?

Comment: You getting ambiguity error because of packages and prices table contain packageCode column thta's why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just you have to change where clause like `packages.packageCode` instead of `packageCode` because `packageCode` in both table so ambiguity error occurs and Remove `TRUE` word from where clause.

```
SELECT COUNT(packages.id) AS rowCount,
       packages.packageCode
FROM packages
INNER JOIN prices ON packages.packageCode = prices.packageCode
WHERE packages.packageCode LIKE '%EPOP%'
ORDER BY packages.packageName ASC
```

Comment: i didnt do anything, tell me how to upvot?